# Very slow listView adapter

Tags: android, android-listview, adapter, listadapter

I create listView with ArrayAdapter. Every item has many views. This is code of getView() method:

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_list_view, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.date = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.date);
        holder.multi_chat = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.multi_chat);
        holder.my_userpick = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.my_userpic);
        holder.name = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        holder.photo1 = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.photo1);
        holder.photo2 = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.photo2);
        holder.photo31 = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.photo31);
        holder.photo32 = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.photo32);
        holder.photo33 = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.photo33);
        holder.photo41 = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.photo41);
        holder.photo42 = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.photo42);
        holder.photo43 = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.photo43);
        holder.photo44 = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.photo44);

        holder.text = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
        holder.userpic = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.userpic);
        holder.userpick2 = convertView.findViewById(R.id.userpick2);
        holder.userpick3 = convertView.findViewById(R.id.userpick3);
        holder.userpick4 = convertView.findViewById(R.id.userpick4);
        holder.wrapper = (RelativeLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.wrapper);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    if (dialogs != null) {
        if (position == (this.getCount() - 1)) {
            if (dialogs != null) {
                if (dates.size() > 1) {
                    dialogs.getDialogs(dates.size()+20);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (dates.get(position).getChatId() != 0) {
        holder.name.setText(dates.get(position).getTitle());
        holder.multi_chat.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        holder.name.setText(dates.get(position).getUidDates());
        holder.multi_chat.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    if (dates.get(position).getReadState() == 0) {
        holder.wrapper.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.conversation_list_no_read));
    } else {
        holder.wrapper.setBackgroundColor(android.R.color.white);
    }

    holder.text.setText(dates.get(position).getBody());

    int date = dates.get(position).getDate();
    java.util.Date time = new java.util.Date((long) date * 1000);

    if ((time.getDate() == current_date.getDate()) && (time.getMonth() == current_date.getMonth()) && (time.getYear() == current_date.getYear())) {
        holder.date.setText(time.getHours() + ":" + time.getMinutes());
    } else if ((time.getDate() == (current_date.getDate() - 1)) && (time.getMonth() == current_date.getMonth()) && (time.getYear() == current_date.getYear())) {
        holder.date.setText("вчера");
    } else {
        holder.date.setText(time.getDate() + "." + time.getMonth() + "." + (time.getYear()+1900));
    }

    if(!dates.get(position).getPhotoInText().equals("")) {
        loaderWithoutCut.displayImage(dates.get(position).getPhotoInText(), holder.my_userpick, false);
        holder.my_userpick.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.text.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.dialog_rect_bg));
        holder.text.setPadding(10, 0, 10, 0);
        holder.text.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        holder.text.setSingleLine(true);
        holder.text.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.END);
    } else {
        holder.my_userpick.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.text.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
        holder.text.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
        holder.text.setSingleLine(false);
        holder.text.setGravity(Gravity.TOP);
    }


    ArrayList photos = dates.get(position).getUidPhotos();

    if (dates.get(position).getChatId() == 0) {
        if (photos.size() == 1) {
            loaderWithoutCut.displayImage((String) photos.get(0), holder.userpic, false);

            holder.userpick2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.userpick3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.userpick4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.userpic.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }
    } else {
        if ((photos.size() < 3) && (photos.size()>0)) {

            if (photos.size() == 1) {
                holder.photo1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                loaderWithCut.displayImage((String) photos.get(0), holder.photo2, true);
            } else {
                holder.photo1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                loaderWithCut.displayImage((String) photos.get(1), holder.photo2, true);
                if (!((String) photos.get(1)).equals((String) photos.get(0))) {
                    loaderWithCut.displayImage((String) photos.get(0), holder.photo1, true);
                } else {
                    holder.photo1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }

            holder.userpic.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.userpick2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.userpick3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.userpick4.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }

        if (photos.size() == 3) {
            loaderWithCut.displayImage((String) photos.get(0), holder.photo31, true);

            loaderWithoutCut.displayImage((String) photos.get(1), holder.photo32, false);
            loaderWithoutCut.displayImage((String) photos.get(2), (ImageView) holder.photo33, false);


            holder.userpic.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.userpick2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.userpick3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.userpick4.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }

        if (photos.size() >= 4) {
            loaderWithoutCut.displayImage((String) photos.get(0), holder.photo41, false);
            loaderWithoutCut.displayImage((String) photos.get(1), holder.photo42, false);
            loaderWithoutCut.displayImage((String) photos.get(2), holder.photo43, false);
            loaderWithoutCut.displayImage((String) photos.get(3), holder.photo44, false);

            holder.userpic.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.userpick2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.userpick3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.userpick4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }

    }

    if (photos.size() == 0) {

        holder.userpick2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.userpick3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.userpick4.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    }


    final ViewHolder holder2 = holder;
    convertView.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {

            TextView text = holder2.text;
            TextView date = holder2.date;
            TextView name = holder2.name;

            if (hasFocus) {
                text.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));
                date.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));
                name.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));
            } else {
                text.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.dialog_text));
                date.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.dialog_date));
                name.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.friends_text_color));
            }
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}
```

Problem is - list view scrolling working very slow. How i can solve this problem?
code of layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:gravity="center_vertical" android:background="@drawable/list_drawable_settings">
    <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center_vertical" android:id="@+id/wrapper">
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="52dip" android:id="@+id/images" android:layout_margin="6dip"
                      android:layout_height="58dip">
            <com.vk.messenger.views.RoundedConersImageView android:id="@+id/userpic"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                       />
            <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/userpick2"
                          android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <LinearLayout android:layout_width="26dip"
                              android:layout_height="58dip">
                    <com.vk.messenger.views.ScalledImageView android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                               android:cropToPadding="true" android:layout_width="26dip"
                               android:layout_height="58dip"
                               android:id="@+id/photo1"/>
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout android:layout_width="26dip"
                              android:layout_height="58dip">
                    <com.vk.messenger.views.ScalledImageView android:layout_width="26dip"
                                                             android:layout_height="58dip" android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                               android:cropToPadding="true"
                               android:id="@+id/photo2"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/userpick3"
                          android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <ImageView android:layout_width="26dip" android:layout_height="58dip" android:id="@+id/photo31"
                        ></ImageView>
                <LinearLayout android:layout_width="26dip" android:id="@+id/userpick3"
                              android:layout_height="58dip"
                              android:orientation="vertical">
                    <ImageView android:layout_width="26dip"
                               android:scaleType="fitCenter" android:cropToPadding="true"
                               android:layout_height="26dip" android:id="@+id/photo32"
                            ></ImageView>
                    <ImageView android:layout_width="26dip"
                               android:scaleType="fitCenter" android:cropToPadding="true"
                               android:layout_height="29dip" android:id="@+id/photo33"
                            ></ImageView>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout android:layout_width="52dip" android:id="@+id/userpick4"
                          android:layout_height="58dip" android:orientation="horizontal">
                <LinearLayout android:layout_width="26dip"
                              android:layout_height="58dip"

                              android:orientation="vertical">
                    <ImageView android:layout_width="26dip"
                               android:layout_height="29dip" android:id="@+id/photo41"
                            ></ImageView>
                    <ImageView android:layout_width="26dip"
                               android:layout_height="29dip" android:id="@+id/photo42"
                            ></ImageView>
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout android:layout_width="26dip"
                              android:layout_height="58dip"
                              android:orientation="vertical">
                    <ImageView android:layout_width="26dip"
                               android:layout_height="29dip" android:id="@+id/photo43"
                            ></ImageView>
                    <ImageView android:layout_width="26dip"
                               android:layout_height="29dip" android:id="@+id/photo44"
                            ></ImageView>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                      android:layout_toRightOf="@id/images" android:layout_marginLeft="4dip">
            <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical" android:id="@+id/left" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <ImageView android:id="@+id/multi_chat" android:visibility="invisible" android:paddingTop="3dip" android:paddingRight="2dip"
                           android:src="@drawable/multi_chat"
                           android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        />
                <com.vk.messenger.views.TextViewMyriadPro android:id="@+id/name" android:text="" android:singleLine="true" android:ellipsize="end"
                          android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                          android:textColor="@color/friends_text_color" android:textSize="16dip" android:textStyle="bold"
                          android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1"/>
                <com.vk.messenger.views.TextViewHelvetica android:id="@+id/date" android:layout_marginLeft="6dip" android:gravity="right" android:layout_marginRight="6dip" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textColor="@color/dialog_date"
                                                          android:textSize="13dip"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                          android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_marginTop="2dip">
                <com.vk.messenger.views.RoundedConersImageView android:id="@+id/my_userpic" android:visibility="gone" android:paddingRight="2dip"
                           android:layout_height="30dip" android:layout_width="30dip"/>
                <com.vk.messenger.views.TextViewHelvetica android:id="@+id/text" android:text="текст" android:layout_below="@id/name"
                          android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:layout_marginLeft="3dip" android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
                          android:textColor="@color/dialog_text" android:textSize="13dip"
                          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                          android:layout_width="fill_parent" />
            </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: If that is your row layout then it's no surprise the `ListView` is slow.

Comment: What's the point of all those sub-layouts? Try to do it in as few layout types as possible.

Comment: The principle - should be able to display 1, 2, 3 or 4 images in different items. All images download asynchronly from internet. Is there a way to create more effective layout?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are simply doing too much in the getview, all that code has to run for every visible list item every time you try to scroll, there is simply too much happening.

Also what are those loadWithCut/loadWitoutCut? where are you loading the images from? are you manipulating the images in the getview?

I would first try to move any object creation out of the getView if possible, then do some logging in the various methods to see where exactly the slowness is occurring.

Comment: loadWithCut/loadWitoutCut - class, that asynchronly load images from Internet. I think that this vorking slowly becouse i have very much setVisibility(). Is there a way to arrange RelativeLayouts with pictures in a certain order, instead of setVisibility? can you help to create more simplify layout but with all this pictures?
The principle - should be able to display in different elements 1, 2, 3 or 4 images.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at getting rid of your nested `LinearLayouts`. You should be using a `RelativeLayout`, rather than nested `LinearLayouts`; especially if you are nesting `LinearLayouts`. Being that you are using so many images, you may want to consider restructuring you layout. Here is an article that talks about the how and why:

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/02/android-layout-tricks-1.html

You might also consider breaking up your `getView` method, there is a lot going on in there. `getView` is has to perform most of that code for each call, is probably contributing to the problem. You should consider creating another class.

Comment: I don't see a solution. Problem in that - i must have opportunity to display 1,2,3 or 4 images with different sizes and location. How to do it? Please, give me an idea)